# VBA code not selecting a value from a dropdown that has a class but no id

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have some code which is meant to open an IE page and fill in the first drop-down to show "caravan". However my code is not selecting caravan from the drop-down.

The website is:

https://insurance.qbe.com.au/portal/caravan/form/estimate

When I right-click to inspect the source code of the drop-down I get directed to the following:

[image]

When I expand the source code below this, I see the following:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the values associated with the drop-down are well below the source code I was initially directed to.

Here is the code I've been using to try and select 'caravan':

```
Sub GetQuote()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate ("https://insurance.qbe.com.au/portal/caravan/form/estimate")
IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

Dim lists, l
Set lists = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)

For Each l In lists

If InStr(1, l.className, "form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid", 1) Then
l.SelectedIndex = 0
End If

Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

End Sub
```

With the above code I was trying to select 'caravan' by referencing the very last bit of the source code I pasted above (i.e. by getting all select tags and then checking all items within the tag until an item whose class name contains "form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" is found, and then selecting index 0 for the value associated with this item. And this obviously didn't work - so here's other code I have tried, again with no luck (it's a slight modification of the code above, by simply referencing the source code that I was initially directed to when I inspected the drop-down, and that would be the very first source code I pasted):

```
For Each l In lists
If InStr(1, l.className, "ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched", 1) Then
     l.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of variations through the course of the day but I'm getting nowehere. I've got what looks ridiculous now, as I've tried removing everything from the `Dim lists, l` to the `Next` lines and replaced it all with `IE.document.elements("z-async-select-mobile").SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: I just can't really seem to see what is the right source code to manipulate, for starters

Comment: Have you tried to get all input elements, i'll have a play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this offer any help, not sure if it's your solution, but added here for formatting.

```
Sub test()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim inputCollection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim inputElement As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.navigate ("https://insurance.qbe.com.au/portal/caravan/form/estimate")

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.Visible = 1

Set htmlDoc = ie.document

Set inputCollection = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INput")

For Each inputElement In inputCollection

    Debug.Print inputElement.className

Next inputElement
```

'     or like this

```
Set inputElement = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")(0)


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - using the last bits of your code (and modifying it with a Msgbox I managed to see that it was at least calling up each of the class names that are stored within the input tag) I'm still not able to select caravan from the dropdown list

Comment: Use the objects from Web Controls and HTML to set it correctly, then you can use Locals and Intellisense to allow you to access the select list items.

Comment: inputElement.Value = "Caravan"

Comment: Thanks again - wondering if you managed to run the code and if it therefore worked for you?

Comment: Wow! It finally worked - although, unsurprisingly, it changed the first three inputs to all be "Caravan". How do I control the input tags so that, for the second input tag, the code will select a year (and "Caravan" will stay as "Caravan" in the first list). I guess the problem is that all of the first three fields have identical classnames within the input tag.

Comment: Or, in other words, I want the value of the first inputElement in the inputCollection to be "Caravan" and the value of the second inputElement in the inputCollection to be "2016" - however, both of these inputElements have identical classnames and belong to the same inputCollection

Comment: Do a bit of reading yourself on it, I cant write the whole thing :)

Comment: Okay, what should I search for exactly? Because I've tried searching online, I've read a lot of posts but none seem to really address my issue

Comment: I've found out how to do this - you need to "getAttribute" (i.e. a non-id or a non-classname attribute) and set it to the actual name of the unique attribute. So the very last "Set inputElement" line in the code above needs to be replaced by something like `If inputElement.getAttribute("placeholder") = "Caravan type" Then

    inputElement.Value = "Caravan"`

Comment: And yeah, that came after a TON of reading after the ton of reading I had already done before Nathan_Sav told me to do a bit of reading :)